# create screenshot of webpage using html2canvas (unable to initialize properly)

Tags: javascript, html, screenshot, html2canvas

I am attempting to use http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/ to take screenshots of my webpage.  I am unable to initialize a canvas element using...

```
var canvas = $('body').html2canvas();
```

If I were able to get a proper canvas I would follow with something like

```
var dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL(); //get's image string
window.open(dataUrl);             // display image
```

Unfortunately, the documentations is very limited IMO. http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/documentation.html . I do not believe I need to preload as I am not using any dynamic graphics(but am not even getting that far anyways)

I am simply too noob to understand if this guy is having success with [screen capturing using html2canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074292/screen-capturing-using-html2canvas)

I don't seem to be getting any farther than this fellow..
[How to upload a screenshot using html2canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9250505/how-to-upload-a-screenshot-using-html2canvas)

My ideal solution would demonstrate how to create screenshot with minimal code. (Copy html to canvas. get toDataURL string. output string)

ANY insight is GREATLY appreciated =)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You should use it this way:

```
$('body').html2canvas();
var queue = html2canvas.Parse();
var canvas = html2canvas.Renderer(queue,{elements:{length:1}});
var img = canvas.toDataURL();
window.open(img);
```

It took me few hours to figure it out, how to use it the right way.
The `{elements:{length:1}}` is required, due to incomplete implementation of the plugin, otherwise you'll get an error.

Good luck!

Comment: i am trying to grab a div like "$("#myDiv").html2canvas();" but i keep getting the whole screen.  how can i fix this?

Comment: The position and the size of the element must be defined

Comment: and how do you define that ?

Comment: something like this `<div style="width:300px;height:300px;"></div>`

Answer (score 12):

You could also use the following:

```
var html2obj = html2canvas($('body'));

var queue  = html2obj.parse();
var canvas = html2obj.render(queue);
var img = canvas.toDataURL();

window.open(img);
```

Comment: how to get screenshot particular div content

Comment: @srini use another selector instead of body like `var html2obj = html2canvas($('#any'));`

Comment: I got this Error: html2obj.parse is not a function

Answer (score 9):

To just get a part of the page you can use it this way:

```
$('#map').html2canvas({
onrendered: function( canvas ) {
  var img = canvas.toDataURL()
  window.open(img);
}
```

Comment: In this scenario how would you pass in the options? (ie if you wanted to turn on logging or adjust the timeout.

Answer (score 8):

This is what worked for me.

```
html2canvas(document.body, {
   onrendered: function(canvas) {
     var img = canvas.toDataURL()
     window.open(img);
  }
});
```

This created a new window for the screenshot.

I only wanted a portion of my page in the screenshot, specifically a container div. So I did the following:

```
html2canvas($('#myDiv'), {
   onrendered: function(canvas) {
     var img = canvas.toDataURL()
     window.open(img);
  }
});
```

For people looking up the same question, if the above options don't help, hopefully this will.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code to capture a screenshot and download the screenshot.

**html button creation**

```
<button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" style="margin:0px 0px -10px 970px; padding:2px 4px 1px 4px" onclick="genScreenshot()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></button>
<a id="test"></a>
<div id="box1"></div>
```

**function definition**

```
<script type="text/javascript">                         
function genScreenshot() {
html2canvas(document.body, {
  onrendered: function(canvas) {
  $('#box1').html("");

  if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE ") > 0 || 
                navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./)) 
        {
    var blob = canvas.msToBlob();
    window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob,'Test file.png');
  }
  else {
    $('#test').attr('href', canvas.toDataURL("image/png"));
    $('#test').attr('download','screenshot.png');
    $('#test')[0].click();
  }


  }
});
}  
</script>
```

**note**: I have created a html button where I have called the function. `test` is an attribute and `box1` is to get the canvas elements.

Answer (score 0):

I have try this way and it working fine for me, you can try this one also.
https://github.com/vijayowork/screenshot-of-div-using-javascript.

I using domtoimage method.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33571921)