# How to capture the whole webpage as an image of any format using jQuery or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I want to capture the whole web page's HTML along with the values of the input fields in that html and images also. I tried searching and got it can be done by canvas, but it doesn't work for IE6, 7, 8.

Can any one tell me how to do it?

Thanks

Comment: You can user html2canvas plugin and if necessary, add excanvas plugin to make it work with IE
Here is some related issue
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10778105/html2canvas-output-selected-div-php/10778719#10778719

Comment: duplicate --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7618368/how-to-capture-the-screen-using-javascript http://stackoverflow.com/questions/701798/how-to-take-a-screen-shot-of-a-web-page

Comment: possible duplicate of [Take a screenshot of a webpage with javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60455/take-a-screenshot-of-a-webpage-with-javascript) [*My Answer*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60455/take-a-screenshot-of-a-webpage-with-javascript/6919676#6919676)