# how to return value from this javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html2canvas

I'm working with [html2canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) and I have the next function

```
hml2canvas($('body'), {
   onrendered: function(canvas) {           
         data = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
    }
});
```

Now, I want to return the data value, so I tried this

```
html2canvas($('body'), {
    onrendered: (this, imgBase64)         
});

var data;
function imgBase64(canvas) {
     data = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
}
console.log(data);
```

but when I see the console I get "undefined". If I put `console.log(data);` inside the `imgBase64` function I get the base64 of the image, but I need the `data`  out of that function to make another work with it. 
Any ideas? 
Thanks.

Comment: You're logging `data` before the `imgBase64` is ever called.

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=asynchronous+variable+javascript

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish with `onrendered: (this, imgBase64)`? I'm not even sure that's valid syntax.

Comment: Asynchronous code explained through Ajax: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/1331430 the same principle applies.

Comment: @jbabey: Technically it is valid syntax, two expressions separated by a comma operator but probably not what OP intended to do. Check this jsbin, it throws all sorts of warnings but the code works http://jsbin.com/ucomir/1/edit

Comment: The comma operator will return the last expression's return value after evaluating the expressions.

Comment: Minifiers use the comma operator everywhere, it's quite useful in one liner return statements, ie `return this.foo = 'foo', this;`

Comment: @elclanrs thanks but the link didn't work for me. About this [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14716630/how-to-return-value-from-this-javascript-function#comment20586257_14716630) what should be the proper way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12196246/1418118) so I modified to adapt to my needs.

```
var html2obj = html2canvas($('body'));
var queue  = html2obj.parse();
var canvas = html2obj.render(queue);
var data = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
```

this way I have the `data` to use later.