# How can I get screenshot of image using html2canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html2canvas

I am trying to save screenshot of image using html2canvas. Below is my code:

```
        var a = document.getElementById('a2')
        html2canvas(document.getElementById('a1'), {
            onrendered: function(canvas) {
            var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
            window.open(img);
                    }
        }
```

However, the code is saving the screenshot for local image. But for the image from external source like : 
http://europa.promaticstechnologies.com/QuotePic/img/QuotePro/bg1.jpg
giving me black screenshot. Please assist.

Comment: probably because of cross origin

Comment: check it this link may be its useful for use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10457608/create-screenshot-of-webpage-using-html2canvas-unable-to-initialize-properly

Answer (score 0):

To use image from external domain you may want to use crossOrigin attribute and current Date as a parameter to src attribute.

e.g.

```
var image = document.createElement('img');
image.onload = function () {
// onload callback
}
image.setAttribute('crossOrigin', '');
image.src = url + '?' + new Date().getTime();
```

Check [this](http://html.com/attributes/img-crossorigin/) for details.

Comment: it says image.setAttribute is not a function.